# Does jwplayer supports RTSP Streaming?

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, rtsp

I am a newbie in video Streaming . I am using jwplayer for my video need. Does it also supports RTSP streaming . If so, How I can play a streaming video via RTSP on jwplayer.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTSP is not supported.

Here is what we support - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

Answer (score 2):

JWPlayer [officially supports](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference) two streaming protocols: **HLS** and **RTMP**.

You might be able to make a fallback and play the **RTSP** stream only on the devices that support it:

```
<div id="player"><a href="rtsp://...">RTSP Link</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        sources: [{
            file: "rtmp://..."
        },{
            file: "http://..."
        }],
        rtmp: {
            bufferlength: 3
        },
        fallback: false
    });
</script>
```

[[Source]](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?484-How-to-use-JW-Player-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine)